# How can I raise an exception, in a button's logic, without having my view out of sync?

Tags: openerp-7

In OpenERP 7, when I'm in a Form view and I click a button (different from "Save" button), before processing the button's logic the form attempts to be saved (either created, or written).

If my button runs and finds an unexpected condition (e.g. data and/or state are not valid), an exception is thrown. The concept behind the exception is expected: we programmed where to raise an `osv.except_osv`, and it raises as expected.

However, when an exception is raised, the view is out of sync (e.g. if the object -e.g. sale.order in my case- has children, and one additional child is created -e.g. sale.order.line- and the button is pressed). The reason behind, is that the view got an exception from processing the button, and so it will not update as always does.

If, after getting an exception, I click any button (even the Save button), this behavior happens:

For the "Discard" button: If -after clicking the button raising the exception- I click "Discard", another exception will be raised: "Uncaught Record not correctly loaded", and the view and its related views will crash until I refresh the browser.

For any other button: If -after clicking the button raising the exception- I click the button, any new element will be created AGAIN. If I create a new sale.order.line and click the exception-raising button, the new entry will be saved and, since the view does not know about it (since it got an exception and never refreshed), clicking any button will try to save the object and its children again (including creating the new elements, again). As conclusion: If I create a new child, and click the exception-raising button N times, and finally a button which does not cause exceptions, I will get N+1 new children (when I only intended one new child).

**Question**: How can I prevent that? How can I trigger an exception inside a button's behavior (a button with type: object) without getting my view out of sync?

Comment: Maybe overriding the method from the button is a solution for you

Comment: Neh, it is the same. At the end is just a method raising an exception